# Sticky Posts on Top of Category Query

Tags: wordpress, random, categories, sticky

I use this query on the Frontpage to display three posts from specific categories in a wp_query. The articles in the query are displayed randomly.

Now the posts that are sticky would like to stay on top and the remaining two articles would still be randomly distributed. Is this possible with a wp_query?

This snippet only returns the one sticky post and the remaining articles are not displayed. Why?

```
           <?php

$args = array(
      'cat'=>'11, 12,20,24',
       'posts_per_page'=> '3',
       'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
       'orderby'=> 'rand'
);

// Custom query.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        // Contents of the queried post results go here.

    }

}

// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use two query

1) for sticky post

```
$args = array(
   'cat'=>'11, 12,20,24',
   'posts_per_page'=> '1',
   'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'orderby'=> 'rand'
);
```

2) Other posts

```
$args = array(
   'cat'=>'11, 12,20,24',
   'posts_per_page'=> '2',
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'orderby'=> 'rand'
);
```

3) Set counter

```
 $count = 0;
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
   // added if condition here if($count == 1){}else{}
   $count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your proposal only partially solves my problem. If there is no sticky post, then only two posts will be displayed. That would not be so nice. I would like to display three posts and if one of these posts is a sticky-post, I want it to stay on top while the other two are still displayed randomly. I have read something about merge_arrays.  But unfortunately I am not the expert to use this example with me.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/using-categories-stickyness-together

You got any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, your approach does not solve my problem.

Comment: What is error you have in my code using can you please tell me?

Comment: I already answered that above. By default, I want to randomly display three posts from certain categories. If a post from one of these is marked as sticky-post, then it should stay on top, whereas the other two posts should still be displayed randomly. In your example, by default I'll display two posts randomly and the other post only if it's marked as sticky-post. This is not what I wanted?

Comment: Use first query with post_per_page => 3 set counter and make it 1 is sticky and other not sticky.

Comment: Maybe you have a code example? Where do I put a counter?

Comment: I've change my answer please take a look on it.